# Using jQuery to pull values from a select element

Tags: jquery

I have a select element in part of my page, and a form all the way on the bottom. I'm trying to populate one of the form variables with the value of the select element like this:

```
<input type="hidden" value="valuefromselectelement..." name="foo" id="foo"/>
```

How can I do that? Presume the select element has the id `currencySelect`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should handle the form's `onsubmit` event

and put `$('#foo').val($('#currencySelect').val());`

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#foo").val($("#currencySelect").val());
```